# Cannot add gmail account on iOS

Tags: ios, mail.app, contacts, gmail, google

I am trying to add a gmail account to my iPad in order to have contacts, email, and calendar sync.  I go to Settings -> Mail -> Accounts -> Add Account and enter my gmail credentials.  It accepts the credentials and then goes to this screen:
[image: post authentication screen]

The spinner to the left of Gmail will spin for about 20 seconds then it just takes me back to this screen:
[image: add account screen]

The account never gets added.  I get an email on my phone that says "new sign in from iPad" so I know the authentication is working.

I am using iOS 10.2.

The same problem existed in 10.0.2.

Some users have reported that doing this process over 4g rather than WiFi works, but this is a WiFi only device.

The gmail app is installed and logs me in just fine.

The same thing happens on both my 2 factor authentication account and my account without 2FA.

Comment: Even i also was facing the same issue. The reason for me was that i was using my outlook ID to signin to Google. I had everything on Google except a gmail ID. So when i sign in, iOS was trying to access the Gmail account also, but it coudn't. It goes back to the account adding page. The solution i found was logging in and going to Gmail where it always promted to create a gmail address. I created a gmail address and now i have Gmail in my Google account, i tried logging in again and it worked on my iPhone running iOS 10.3.

Comment: On Monday 2nd April one of my iPhone GMail accounts (my main one helpfully!) showed 'Cannot get Mail, the mail server "imap.gmail.com" is not responding...'. I had changed nothing. I read a bit, deleted the account, then tried to re-add. Then suffered the same problem above. Looking on my iMac it was not showing a problem but not refreshing. By 15:30 on Monday the connection was working. I have other GMail accounts which work. I am unsure of where to go now!

Comment: The wifi switch off does not work. Geofencing this is strange. I have bought storage but that appears to be fine. As a result I am rather purplexed

Comment: @AjithMemana Had the same problem. It was not working because I did not have a gmail address assigned to my google account.

Comment: @AjithMemana I think your suggestion deserves to be an answer too :)

Comment: Adding GMail to the Google account fixed this for me also. Thanks @AjithMemana

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too.

When I checked on google if there was a security issue (https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) I noticed that my iphone location was overseas.

I then realised that iPhone was connected to my company wifi and was routed via their overseas hub.

So I disabled the wifi so that only the local mobile data was being used.

After that the add mail > google then worked.

Comment: I had to use the company wifi instead of 4G

Comment: Wifi or 4g data connection. nothing works for me.

Comment: @NSNull I turned off WiFi and *also* quit out of both the Mail and Settings apps. Not sure if quitting and re-launching was necessary, but if disabling WiFi alone doesn't work, that's one more thing to try. It worked for me.